# Sending multiple parameter from angularjs to spring rest controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-restcontroller

How do i send multiple parameter using Angular POST to Spring Rest.

Below is my Spring REST Method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report/generate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public byte[] generateReport(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params, @RequestParam(value = "reportType") ReportType reportType) {
```

Below is my AngularJS POST call.

```
var req = {
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/report/generate',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data :  {reportType : reportType, params : params }
            }

            var promise = $http(req)
                .then(
                    function successCallback(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log("Error saving client details!! Try again...");
                        return response;
                    }
            );
            return promise;
```

The 2nd parameter ReportType is a type enum so sending String from AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

your sintax here is not valid

```
data :  params, reportType
```

`data` is an object that will be send as a json to your server, you can put as many key value pairs as you want.

```
data: {
 whateverKey: whateverValue
 reportType: ReportType
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post

Comment: Tried that too, getting http 400
Below is what i can see raw request from browser.
`{"params":{"clientId":"58fb99e4b153470f4617645d"},"reportType":"CLIENT_DETAIL_REPORT"}`

Comment: I removed reportType parameter from SpringRestController, and i see that it's mapping everything to Map<String,Object> params. Logically it never know which one is Map parameter. I understood the issue, but i still don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: mm probably you have some server side issue. the client code looks fine with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below sample code to build your data object.

```
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('key1', value1);
                    fd.append('key2',value2);



var req = {
                method : 'POST',
                url : '/report/generate',
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                },
                data :  fd
            }

            var promise = $http(req)
                .then(
                    function successCallback(response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log("Error saving client details!! Try again...");
                        return response;
                    }
            );
            return promise;
```